# how to replace specific values in data frame to NA in R?

Tags: r

I am working with a data frame in R and I want to replace the values of certain id to NA. Here is an example of the input file.

```
id  y
222 12
432 23
522 22
443 11
```

And here is my desired output:

```
id  y
222 12
432 NA
522 22
443 NA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
idsToBeReplaced <- c(432, 443)    
df[df$id %in% idsToBeReplaced, "y"] <- NA

#  id  y
#1 222 12
#2 432 NA
#3 522 22
#4 443 NA
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it is perfect. I was spending hours to figure it out.